About vocals and music
The vocals are allowed in Islam or not ?? If only vocals are allowed in Islam and if someone is praying near u that u are just signing vocals so it is Haram or not ? Kindly answer it ...I know u should pray there where is peace and loneliness but if that situation occur so it is Haram or not??? Singing only vocals beside someone who is praying??it's just like that we are talking to someone and other person is praying or it is Haram??
